# How to abort in RedBean's update hook

Tags: php, redbean

I have to do some validation in my Model and then abort if something went wrong. In a simplified version, it would look like this:

```
class Model extends RedBean_SimpleModel
{
    public function update()
    {
        if(method_exists($this, 'validate') and ! $this->validate())
            $this->abort(); // made-up method
    }
}
```

The thing is this `abort` method (or similar) doesn't seem to exist. The docs suggests to do it with Exceptions but I wanted the proccess to be more transparent. I couldn't catch the exception inside the Model code (to avoid repetition, since i already know what to do with the errors).

A solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325720/validation-in-redbean-php) was to open a transaction and then rollback on errors. But I really don't want this kind of overhead. Any thougths?